# onSearch event on React Multiselect Dropdown?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have used the `multiselect-react-dropdown` library for implement MultiSelect dropdown. I this library have two props: one is **options** and second is **onSearch**. In options props passed the data which is showing on dropdown. user can select the data from it. But onSearch is used on search user's by api. So how can i manage both the data on dropdown. Please help me to solve this.

```
                        <Multiselect
                        onSearch={(e) => callSearchApi(e)}
                        placeholder="Select Contributor"
                        onSelect={onSelect}
                        closeIcon="circle"
                        options={UsersData} 
                        displayValue="name"
                      />
```

**API Call**

```
 const callSearchApi = (name) => {
    console.log('callSearchApi', name);
    collaboratorsSearch(name)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('callSearchApi fetch user', response.data.results);
      
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('callSearchApi fetch user Error', error);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement this feature you need to use react hook **useState** here.

You need to set below state and hooks. I am setting options inside **useEffect** here but in your case you can set it in button click event.

```js
const [ selectedOptionValue, setSelectedOptionValue ] = useState('');

const [ options, setOptions ] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 setOptions(Data);
}, [])
```

You can toggle **options** data based on your requirement. Set this options variable either from **callSearchApi** or from **props**.

I have implemented **onSearch** and **callSearchApi** function here. Just to reduce the code I am using **async** and **await**.

```js
const callSearchApi = async (value) => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/?name='+ value);
    const users = await response.json();
    if (users && users.length > 0) {
     setOptions(users);
    } else {
      setOptions(Data);
    }
};

const onSearch = (value) => {
    console.log('Value', value)
    callSearchApi(value);  
}
```

Please note I have used dummy API here which gives users information.

Here is the complete code.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import Multiselect from 'multiselect-react-dropdown';
import { Data } from "./data";

export default function App() {

  const [ selectedOptionValue, setSelectedOptionValue ] = useState('');

  const [ options, setOptions ] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
   setOptions(Data);
  }, [])

  const onSelect = (selectedList, selectedItem) => {
    
  }

  const onRemove = (selectedList, removedItem) => {
    
  }

  const callSearchApi = async (value) => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/?name='+ value);
    const users = await response.json();
    if (users && users.length > 0) {
     setOptions(users);
    } else {
      setOptions(Data);
    }
   
  
  };

  const onSearch = (value) => {
    console.log('Value', value)
    callSearchApi(value);
    
  }



  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>

      {
       
        // options? options.length : null

        options? (  <Multiselect
                      onSearch={onSearch}
                      options={options} // Options to display in the dropdown
                      selectedValues={selectedOptionValue} // Preselected value to persist in dropdown
                      onSelect={onSelect} // Function will trigger on select event
                      onRemove={onRemove} // Function will trigger on remove event
                      displayValue="name" // Property name to display in the dropdown options
                      />): null
      }
    
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can find working example [here on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aipzhq?file=src/App.js).